# Include font awesome inside input type text

Tags: css, icon-fonts

I´m trying to include a Font Awesome inside my input in left side but I´m not having sucess. I never used awesome fonts to this purporse. Anyone there knows how to include the font inside the input? Thanks!

**The font Im trying to include in left side of my input:**

```
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
```

**My html:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
       <input type="text"class="inputs" placeholder="e-mail" /> 
       <br />
       <input type="password" class="inputs"placeholder="Password"  />

</form>
```

**My css:**

```
 inputs:-webkit-input-placeholder { 
        color:    #b5b5b5; 
    } 

    inputs-moz-placeholder { 
        color:    #b5b5b5; 
    } 

     .inputs  { 
        background: #f5f5f5; 
        font-family:"bariol_regularregular", Palatino, serif;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
        border-radius: 3px; 
        border: none; 
        padding: 13px 10px; 
        width:180px; 
        margin-bottom: 10px; 
        box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px rgba( 0,0,0,0.1 ); 
        height:20px;
    } 

    .inputs:focus { 
        background: #fff; 
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #96842E; 
        outline: none;    
    }
```

Comment: Do you want the icon to remain there while the user enters in their email?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be achieved with some absolute positioninig. There are two different ways I can think of doing this so I will show you both. Fiddle with both examples [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V9T8H/)

**Method 1**

*HTML*

```
<label id="email-label">
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="email here" />
</label>
```

*CSS*

```
#email {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#email-label {
    position: relative;
}
#email-label:before {
    color: #666;
    content:"\f007";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

**Method 2**

*HTML*

```
<label id="email-label2">
    <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
    <input type="text"id="email2" placeholder="email here" />
</label>
```

*CSS*

```
#email-label2 {
    position: relative;
}

#email-label2 .fa-rocket {
    color: #666;
    top: 2px;
    left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}

#email2 {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man..it works! I need to study the position relative and fixed because I didnt understand nice yet! Thank you one more time for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I purpose this :

HTML

```
<i class="inside fa fa-user"></i>
<input type="text" class="inp" placeholder="Your account" />
```

CSS

```
.inside {
position:absolute;
text-indent:5px;
margin-top:2px;
color:green;
}

.inp {
text-indent:20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ga6j5345/1/